# twocolumnfalse overlaps Image and Text

Tags: graphics, floats, two-column

I am writing a document in the two column format and wished to spread an image spanning both the columns. So,my code snippet for the image is as follows:

```
 \twocolumn[\begin{figure}
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5in, height = 4in]{SomeSampleAnswers.png}
    \caption{Some Outputs generated by the Learning Model}
    \label{fig:sample_figure}
       \end{@twocolumnfalse} 
     \end{figure}]
```

Unfortunately, this causes the text below(back to standard 2-column format)
to overlap in the image area. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Most classes have a `figure*` environment for figures above both columns.

Answer (score 2):

The following code resolves the issue.

```
\usepackage{cuted}% for environment `strip`
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

in document:

```
\begin{strip}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{\blindtext}
\end{strip}
```